# Eclipse Package Explorer '>' Symbol Before File Names

Tags: eclipse

This question is tough to search for as the '>' symbol seems to be ignored in Stack Overflow's search, so I apologize if it's been asked and answered before.

In Eclipse's package explorer view it will append a '>' symbol to the start of a file name if that file has been edited since it has last been synchronized with a repository. The problem with this is the '>' symbol is then taken into account when selecting files with the keyboard.

Say there's a file titled Main.java. If it hasn't been edited since synchronizing you can type  'Main' when the package explorer has focus and that file would get selected. However if the file has been edited you would have to type in '>Main' for it to get selected.

Does anybody know if this is a feature that can be disabled? I haven't found anything searching through Eclipse's menus, and I haven't been able to find anybody else mentioning this online.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Preferences `Team > SVN > Label Decorations`. You can change the format (and thus the position) in `Text Decorations` (e.g. "File": "{outgoing_flag} {name} {revision}") and set non-textual icons for outgoing changes in `Icons Decorations`.

This is for Subversive team provider, Subclipse uses a different design. Maybe you will find the settings two times.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it! My office uses CVS but I was able to find the same option for that under Preferences->Team->CVS->Label Decorations->Text Decorations tab->Outgoing Change flag.

Comment: Just for future reference for anybody who finds this answer, I found a better solution than simply removing the '>' character from the 'Outgoing Change flag' field. The 'File Decoration', 'Folder Decoration', and 'Project Decoration' settings on that screen let you change the order of different variables. I moved the 'outgoing_change_flag' so it's right after 'name'. Now I can still see which files have changes easily without it messing up the selection.

Answer (score 2):

The selection of a leaf of your tree is the default behavior of the underlying Tree Widget which is rendered by your operating system. Since a native Tree doesn't know something about Decorators (the '>' is drawn by a decorator from your team provider) the text of a leaf contains the '>' character. To open a resource use the much more comfortable shortcut
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse goto preferences

Goto General -> Apperance -> Label Decorations -> Unckeck GIT

or SVN if you are using SVN. In my case i am using GIT.