# Eclipse shows known file icon in android project import

Tags: android, eclipse

After I imported my old project to eclipse all the folders and file icons changed to unknown animation. Please look at the attached image. What is the reason for this and how can I fix it? [This is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFzOh.jpg)

Comment: means folder / file icon shows unknown icon

Comment: This is not the unknown icon. But a sign of changes in your source files with respect to remote source code that you placed such as on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The signs `(>)` that you are seeing in `Package Explorer` are not the unknown signs but are valid which tells the changes in the files with respect to that on the remote repository for that remotely connected source code.

Please look at the post [eclipse-package-explorer-symbol-before-file-names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212996/eclipse-package-explorer-symbol-before-file-names) for clarification.